# Exception trying to connect a service in a docker container to eureka in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

I am trying to connect a eureka client in one docker container to a eureka server in another docker container.

I am trying to connect via the service name set up in my

In my docker docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
 eureka-server:
   image:  eurekaservice
   hostname: eureka-server
   container_name: eurekahost
   ports:
     - "8761:8761"
```

In my eureka properties file I have

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
server.port=8761

eureka.client.registerWithEureka = false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = false
eureka.instance.hostname=eurekahost
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone  = http://eurekahost:8761/eureka
```

in my eureka client properties file I have

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=user-service

eureka.client.registerWithEureka = true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry = true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone  = http://eurekahost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.instance.preferIpAddress = false
eureka.instance.hostname= eurekahost
```

I run the Eureka with docker-compose up

Then i start up the client service with

docker run -p 8083:8080 bankuser

i get the following exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8761 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
       at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
```

Cant figure out what I am missing.

Comment: can you share `application.yaml` file ?

Comment: I am using application.properties and have share both the  Eureka properties file and the  Eureka client  properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Updated properties to yml file for ease of reading

application.yml for eureka server

```
server:
  port=8761
spring:
  application: eureka-service

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eurekahost
  client:
    validateCertificates: false
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekahost:8761/eureka
```

application.yml for eureka client

```
server:
  port=8080
spring:
  application: name=user-service

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: eurekahost
  client:
    validateCertificates: true
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekahost:8761/eureka
    instance:
      preferIpAddress: false
```

If